# iperf 2.1.9 bidirectional test cant figure out the server-client flow

Tags: networking, server, bandwidth, iperf

I'm trying to calculate the throughput of the server during the bidirectional test. I have a python script that basically scrapes the data out of the logs. But the problem is I'm not able to figure out which one is the server-client communication and which one is client-server.

```
[  2] local 10.233.143.159 port 5001 connected with 10.233.143.141 port 59914 Client connecting to 10.233.143.141,
 UDP port 5001 Sending 1470 byte datagrams, 
IPG target: 560.76 us (kalman adjust) UDP buffer size:  224 KByte (default) 
[ *1] local 10.233.143.159 port 40499 connected with 10.233.143.141 port 5001 (reverse)
```

this is from the server log. Cant quite figure out which is which.

````
 Client connecting to 10.233.143.159,
 UDP port 5001 Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 560.76 us (kalman adjust) 
UDP buffer size: 64.0 KByte (default) 
[  1] local 10.233.143.141 port 65245 connected with 10.233.143.159 port 5001 
[  2] local 10.233.143.141 port 5001 connected with 10.233.143.159 port 34470```

this is the client log. I just want to know the server-client communication from the above given logs.

I tried to use -r instead of -d but got "connection reset by the peer" . So that didnt work out as well. \*\*Can someone help out??PLZZ \*\*
````

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk indicates the traffic flow is reversed. Also, use -e or --enhanced-reports for outputs with more information.